# Call C# mono code from java under linux

Tags: java, c#, linux, mono

I have somoe C# source code that I want to be available for java applications under linux OS.

How can I call some C# method from java code?

I have found http://www.mono-project.com/Java but this looks like writing java code in .net environment. It is not what I look for. Rather I need to create new java library that will expose all functionality from C# code, the new library must be executed in pure java environment. Maybe that is possible with IKVM I am not sure.

Comment: I would recommend you rewrite the code in java. The syntax is very alike and similar. But Mono is available for Linux so if they get Mono they will be able to run your code on a Linux machine. Though C# is a Microsoft language, it can be compiled on other machines with the correct tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page) to compile your C# classes on the Linux platform of your choice;
2. Use [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) to write a set of facade classes between your java code and the compiled C# code.

Answer (score 1):

The closest tool I can find that might be useful would be [JNI4Net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/)

I think you would still need Mono to run a .net framework on Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is going to be closed (I voted too) simply because it would finally lead to a tool recommendation.

Your best approach is to rewrite them in Java. Or alternatively, there are existing tools (commercial or free) to convert C# to Java,

- [CSharpJavaMerger Framework](http://csharpjavamerger.org/how-to-use-csharpjavamerger-for-csharp-developer.html)
- [RemObjects C#](http://www.remobjects.com/elements/hydrogene/) who compiles C# to JVM.
- and many others

Mono is not something you should consider at this moment. Yes, IKVM.NET only helps running Java code on Mono/.NET, and it won't help you in your case.

Comment: But I must not rewrite C# code. That it part of my problem, if solutions is tool or not I am fine just to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you can execute the c# project or not through mono, if you can, then process intercomunication is the way to go.

If you are doing it in Linux I should use a pipe channeling to intercomunicate both processes, works really well and is easy to use.

If you can't execute the c# process, then that's another history, you cannot call directly a .net assembly from java.

And also, using mono on Linux per today gives great results (except for ASP .net), we are using it and are getting really good results (faster responses than Java in most scenarios).